# Connecting Windows to Wireless (802.1x Radius) before login working sporadically

Tags: windows, wifi, login, radius, windows-authentication

We have a system based on Ruckus wireless, connected to a Windows 2012R2 NPS server for RADIUS authentication.

We've long been having issues whereby single sign-on isn't reliable, so we've set up a (hidden) SSID which uses machine authentication against the RADIUS server to connect to wifi at the login screen; the connection then switches to a (higher-priority) standard user authenticated connection post login.

This is working in about 50% of cases.  In a successful test, the machine will boot up and will have immediately connected to the hidden "preauth" network.  A login will occur quickly, and then the connection will switch to the higher-priority network.

In a failed test, the network will not connect automatically.  It will connect when the 'connect' button next to the 'preauth' network is manually clicked, but the automatic connection fails.

I'm not sure where to look at this stage.  The computers themselves don't seem to have much in the way of logs to say why the failure's occurring - it's more like no attempt is made than it's failed in any way.

Has anyone had any success in getting Windows machines to reliably, automatically connect before login?